# Set width of div to match the longest child (not yet appended)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div and I append various values to it.
The div is centered and the children are aligned to the left.
When I add any children that are longer than the ones existing the div bops and expands.
I want to avoid this behavior by setting the width to fit the largest child in advance.

Any ideas?

```js
function appendChildToDiv(stringToAppend) {
  const originalDiv = document.getElementById(`original`);
  originalDiv.innerHTML += `<div id='rest'>${stringToAppend}</div>`;
}
```

```html
<div style='text-align: center;'>
  <div style='display: inline-block; text-align: left;' id='original'>
    <br> this is the first child
    <br> this is the second child
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="appendChildToDiv('I am the longest child of them all');">
  Append long child
</button>
```

Comment: An element that you have not appended to the document yet, does not _have_ any dimensions you could query. You will either have to add them all to a different element (that is not actually shown within the viewport) first, so that you can measure the width of that; or maybe _have_ all the elements exist right away, but hide the ones you don't need to show yet, using a combination of `visibility: hidden` and `height:0` with the overflow cut off, or something like that.

Comment: Perfect! Worked excellently. Thanks :)

Comment: So now the next step is to decide what to do with this question, which has no official answer yet. It seems like @CBroe's hints were helpful, but you're the only one who knows what you actually did to get it working. I suggest you write your own answer to this question, explaining how you solved it. That way, this question may be useful to others in future. Another alternative would be to simply delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up sorting the whole list of children based on the length of them, so that the first element on the list is always the longest.

An alternative that worked was adding the hidden children with `visibility: hidden`.